# Get IdentifyRef fileds data from TFS workitem

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a code that gets a WI Type [Code Review Response]. When trying to get the Created By field of the WI

```
field = {[System.CreatedBy, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.IdentityRef]}
```

or Reviewed By, or Closed By field of the WI, I am getting the string `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.IdentityRef` and not the user name.
It seems there is another, lower level object in it that holds the user data...
How can i get into the user name and details?

For example, when I trying the following code:

```
WorkItem linked_WI = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(linked_WI_ID).Result; 
//set WI object to the linked WI
string linked_WI_Type = linked_WI.Fields["System.WorkItemType"].ToString();
if (linked_WI_Type == "Code Review Response")
{
  string codereview_closed_status = linked_WI.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.ClosedStatus"].ToString();
  string codereview_reviewer = linked_WI.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy"].ToString();
}
```

I am not getting the reviewer name but again the identity reference (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.IdentityRef`) as string.

How can I loop into the Idefntify Ref object and get the user name?

Comment: Try `var reviewr = linkes_WI.Fields["...."]`.Name.ToString();

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try DisplayName property of IdentityRef object:

```
var person = (IdentityRef)linked_WI.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy"];
string codereview_reviewer = person.DisplayName;
```